# Magento 2: In header searching search products collection matching with products name only

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.2, catalogsearch

I want to search product collection matching only with products name not from another like description, sku, attributes etc in Magento 2 header searching.

Answer (score 1):

First you need make every attribute's property  **Use in Search** to **NO.**
from admin.

Navigate to `Admin ->Store > Product> Attribute`.

Fine all attributes which has the value **Yes**  for **Use in Search**.

Make this field value to yes only for the attribute "Product Name" .

Then do an indexing from Index management and then see your result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to filter product collection matching product name with enter text like "Test Shirt" . It should search the full string search. Like get those products collection contains the full string "Test Shirt" no collection  with "Test" or "Shirt".