# How to enable search from product name only in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, search

I am new on magento. Please help me to enable search of product according to **product name** only, on Magento 2.4.

Because I am searching **diaper** and it is showing other products. Please check the below images:

[image: I am searching diaper and it is showing other products]

I tried this but not working: [Magento 2: In header searching search products collection matching with products name only](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/217515/magento-2-in-header-searching-search-products-collection-matching-with-products)

Comment: after the solution have you done reindexing?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya Yes, I did it